# How to set datagrid SelectedIndex to -1 in app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, app.xaml

So I have multiple DataGrids in a single wpf window and in the codebehind I have set the SelectedIndex property of each DataGrid to -1.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dgPackaging.ItemsSource = vm.getPackaging();
    dgUsers.ItemsSource = vm.getUsers();
    dgFarmers.ItemsSource = vm.getAllFarmers();
    dgProducts.ItemsSource = vm.getAllProducts();
    dgPurchaseOrder.ItemsSource = vm.getAllPurchasOrders();
    dgPODescription.ItemsSource = vm.PurchaseOrderDetails;
    dgCustomers.ItemsSource = vm.getAllCustomers();

    dgFarmers.SelectedIndex = -1;
    dgUsers.SelectedIndex = -1;
    dgPackaging.SelectedIndex = -1;
    dgProducts.SelectedIndex = -1;
    dgPurchaseOrder.SelectedIndex = -1;
    dgCustomers.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

I have a style in my app.xaml that all Datagrids use:

```
<Style x:Key="AdminGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource dataGridStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
</Style>
```

I am able to set the SelectedIndex property value to any number greater than or equal to zero.
When I set the property value to -1, the first row of the Datagrids are selected.
So my question is , is it possible to set the SelectedIndex property to -1 in the AdminGridStyle, and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you *don't* set the SelectedIndex property at all if you don't want any item to be selected?

Comment: @mm8 If I remove the SelectedIndex from the codebehind and from the App.xaml and run the program, the first row of each datagrid is still selected

Comment: What if you remove the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem setter?

Comment: @mm8 That worked, thank you!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the `SelectedIndex` property at all if you don't want to select any item in the `DataGrid`(s).

Just remove the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` setter from your `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="AdminGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource dataGridStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"/>
</Style>
```